# When was the topography data for the Apollo 17 landing site gathered?

Tags: lunar-landing

The [presskit for Apollo 17](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a17/A17_PressKit.pdf), released one month before the mission, shows the exact topography of the landing site. The data used to re-construct that topography, when was it collected?

[image]

Comment: I think you mean "topography"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Lunar Orbiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Orbiter_program) program existed primarily to produce a good map of the Moon's surface for use by Apollo.  There were five Lunar Orbiters all-told and the first three were dedicated to mapping the Moon's equatorial region where the initial Apollo landings were planned.  That was successful enough that the last two were put into polar orbits and nearly completed coverage of the whole surface.